# Django - Keep specific fields on form after submit

Tags: django

I have a view that has a simple "save and add another" functionality, that redirects the user to the same page after submit the form.

**View:**

```
def new_planning(request):
    form = PlanningForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        if 'another' in request.POST:
            messages.success(request, ('Success!'))
            return redirect('new_planning')
        else:
            return redirect('list_planning')
    return render(request, 'pages/planning/new_planning.html', context={
        'form': form,
    })
```

**Form:**

```
class PlanningForm(forms.ModelForm):

    accountplan = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=AccountsPlan.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('code'),
    )

    month = forms.DateField(
        required=True,
        error_messages={'required': '', },
    )

    amount = forms.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9,
        decimal_places=2,
        required=True,
        validators=[
        error_messages={'required': '', },
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Planning
        fields = '__all__'
```

The function works as expected and after the submit, the same page is rendered with a blank form. What I want is to keep just the *"amount"* field blank and keep the data typed in the *"accountplan"* and *"month"* fields. Is there a way to do this?

I read about [instance in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#model-instance-reference), but it doesn't seem to be what I looking for, since I don't want to get the data from the database (if that's possible), but simply keep the last inputs typed in both fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions) and [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values). Here's the implementation in case it helps anyone:

```
def new_planning(request):

    # create a key session with the data from the request.POST 
    request.session['planning_form_data'] = request.POST
    # get the key session if exists, else none
    planning_form_data = request.session.get('planning_form_data', None)
    
    #if the key session exists, use initial data to fill the form
    if planning_form_data:
        form = PlanningForm(request.POST, initial={
            'accountplan': planning_form_data['accountplan'],
            'month': planning_form_data['month'],
        })
    #if the key session doesn't exist, open an empty form
    else: 
        form = PlanningForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        if 'another' in request.POST:
            messages.success(request, ('Success!'))
            return redirect('new_planning')
        else:
            return redirect('list_planning')
    return render(request, 'pages/planning/new_planning.html', context={
        'form': form,
    })
```

In my case, it make sense to clear this session data when the user access the *list_planning* page, so i added this in this page view:

```
planning_form_data = request.session.get('planning_form_data', None)
if planning_form_data:
    del request.session['planning_form_data']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the "ModelForm" to a "Model" class, you can get the values of the posted datas, and can be rendered to the page. 
For example:

```
# views.py    
def ContactPageView(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            message = request.POST.get('message')
            message_element = ContactFormObject(email=email, message=message)
            message_element.save()
        else:
            name, message = '', ''
        form_data = name, message
        return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form_data': form_data})
# models.py
class ContactFormObject(models.Model):
        email = models.CharField(max_length=100) #....
```

ModelForm is more comfortable, but I don't recommend it if you have extra 10 minutes to code some HTML in order to the possibilities of more customization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in order to do this, will I have to change my html and put stuff like labels directly in the html? Because if that's the case, doing this will add a lot of work if I need to change label names in the future.

Comment: In this case, yes. But you should rewrite the labels in just 1 place, in another file. Although you can render the forms manually, I don't know how else you could pass the received value to "BoundField.initial".
[BoundField.initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.initial)